# How can eddy currents be measured in a solid metal conductor such as aluminum?

Tags: electromagnetism

In a linear eddy current braking system involving a metal, is there a way to actually measure the eddy currents induced in the metal?

Comment: Hint: currents create a magnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In the case of AC you can use a small pickup coil near the aluminum part and near the driving source of the eddy currents. You wire this "sense" coil in such a manner as to cancel any tendency for a directly-transmitted signal from the drive coil to induce a stray interference signal in the sense coil.  for circuit details, search for "eddy current nondestructive test" on the engineering stack exchange.

In the case of DC you can use a hall effect sensor instead of a pickup coil. Similar comments apply re: cancellation of interference from the magnet that is inducing the eddy currents in the aluminum disc.

Both methods will require sensor calibration against a standard.